# When has pure mathematics been influenced by the social context of mathematicians?

Tags: ho.history-overview, soft-question

I recently learned that the Moscow school of descriptive set theory (Egorov, Lusin, etc.) was deeply influenced by the religious movement of Name Worshiping in Russia, as recounted in Graham and Kantor's book "Naming Infinity". What are some other interesting and well-sourced examples of when the work of pure mathematicians has been influenced by their cultural/social context?

Comment: At least one review does not seem so sure of the authors' thesis: http://cscs.umich.edu/~crshalizi/reviews/naming-infinity/

Comment: I think that a proper answer to this question would require actual historians of mathematics, not "mathematicians who have read some history". There is always a danger of reading the present into the past, and I fear that this kind of question is ripe for such. (Anyone here know of the theological as opposed to empirical impetus behind, say Copernicus? Or the role of politics in Galileo's reputation?)

Comment: Lastly for now: an obvious answer to the question in the title is "always". The more telling but harder question is: "in what ways has it been influenced?" (Even the framing of the question in terms of "pure" mathematics is deeply anachronistic.)

Comment: The review that Yemon Choi linked to mentions a fascinating explanation of what motivated Markov to invent his chains.

Comment: Regarding the final question on matchings: I am pretty sure that  any relation to 'marriage' is only an a posteriori expressive description of some problems so that there should be no relation whatsoever.     

Comment: Following up quid, some very practical problems such as scheduling classes to classrooms can be phrased as matching problems on bipartite graphs -- let one component of the graph be the classes to be offered, the other component be the classrooms, and make an edge if the classroom is large enough to handle the class.  This is one of numerous examples.

Comment: I have heard some great things about this book: http://www.amazon.com/Mathematics-Historical-Context-Spectrum-Suzuki/dp/0883855704 To quote the Amazon description, this book "...explores the complex interaction between mathematics, mathematicians, and society." The author appears to specialize in the history of mathematics. 

Comment: CW?  There is no right answer. 

Comment: Hmm, I would be interested to see a historian of mathematics review the Suzuki book

Comment: @Yermon: "Mathematics in Historical Context" is reviewed by P. A. Kidwell in the American Mathematics Monthly, May 2011.  She is an historian of mathematics.  Her closing sentence is, "Suzuki’s exploration of
mathematics in historical context does not meet this challenge,"
where "this challenge" is a characterization of the best math history.
Here is the JSTOR link: http://www.jstor.org/stable/10.4169/amer.math.monthly.118.05.471

Comment: After some thought and indecision, have cast final vote to close. I suggest that those who might want question reopened should open a thread on meta.MO where the case can be debated

Comment: The definition of "research" level questions in mathematics seems to be very vague --- it seems pretty much anything is fair game on MO these days --- ugh!

Comment: Meta thread http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/1401/examples-of-social-context-influencing-mathematics/ for any further discussion of whether the question is appropriate, cool, etc etc

Comment: Does the death of Archimedes count?  The social context has caused his death, and you can find exaggerated claims about how much he could have advanced mathematics and science and engineering if he lived longer.
 

Comment: A couple of links mentioned in the comments above ([here](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/259738) and [here](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/260357)) are broken, but snapshots are saved on the Wayback Machine ([here](https://web.archive.org/web/20120606193634/http://cscs.umich.edu/~crshalizi/reviews/naming-infinity/) and [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20150512050230/http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/1401/examples-of-social-context-influencing-mathematics/), respectively).

Answer (score 25):

How about this paper:

MR1648209 (99h:01029)
Dauben, Joseph W.
Marx, Mao and mathematics: the politics of infinitesimals.
Proceedings of the International Congress of Mathematicians, Vol. III (Berlin, 1998). 
Doc. Math. 1998, Extra Vol. III, 799–809.

> Throughout the Cultural Revolution, Mao Ze-dong promoted Marxism and dialectics to encourage reforms in all fields of endeavor, including the sciences. In mathematics, this encouraged, as it had Marx, an appreciation (with criticism) of the infinitesimal calculus. For Chinese mathematicians, application of Abraham Robinson's newly created nonstandard analysis not only rehabilitated infinitesimals in a technical sense, but (when understood within an appropriate materialist framework) could be used to justify and promote two new fields of study in China---model theory and nonstandard analysis.

Comment: That's great (makes me almost regret I voted to close the question). Now, that you mention it, I think in some form this came up before on MO. Maybe due to some 'curious' claims of Marx or a correspondent of his, related to Calculus. 

Comment: For more on Mao and math, see

http://formandformalism.blogspot.de/2011/09/lawvere-on-mathematics-and-maoist.html

Comment: Wow, ‘When the main contradictions of a thing have been found, the scientific procedure is to summarize them in slogans which one then constantly uses as an ideological weapon for the further development and transformation of the thing.’ writes Lawvere on the first page of _Quantifiers and Sheaves_.

Comment: I first learnt about Mao and infinitesimals through Adrian Mathias who also wrote this (somewhat polemical) piece on logic and Marxism: https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~ardm/stalin.pdf

Answer (score 14):

Perhaps a case could be made for advances in *cryptography* in the last half-century as driven by the social context of increased need for information security.  I have in mind [zero-knowledge proofs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-knowledge_proof), and, say, the [PCP theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probabilistically_checkable_proof) (PCP=probabilistic checkable proof).

Of course one could reject this as not the work of "pure mathematicians."
Neal Koblitz might serve as a counterexample?

Comment: I'd make this more specific: it's not just the increased need for security, but differences in relevant scenarios.  For example, public key crypto is well adapted to point-to-point communication among strangers, which is crucial for things like e-commerce.  By contrast, private key crypto is fine for hierarchical communication in a fixed organization, which covers many military/government/corporate applications.  This is one reason why public key crypto didn't arise until the 70's.  Regardless of whether you consider it pure math, it had a huge impact on areas like computational number theory.

Comment: This is a good example. Going a little bit further back in the history: the work of Alan Turing and his team in breaking the German cipher was certainly heavily influenced by the society around him. The work ultimately lead to the construction of computers (in a way). Sadly, social pressure on Turing took a turn for the worse after the war.

Answer (score 6):

Certainly probability falls under this scope. Cardano's secretive work on the subject was done to help him in his professional gambling career. Soon after that, Pascal and Fermat worked out the notion of expected values to solve the Chevalier de Méré's gambling question. See Anders Hald's "A history of probability and statistics and their applications before 1750."

Comment: Speaking of Cardano: I've read a somewhat melodramatic history of the solution of the cubic and quartic that places it in by a culture of public mathematical competition, which made a new solution method comparable to a prepared opening variation in a chess or checkers match.  I don't know whether this is still the accepted history.
(It's also a nice story that this discovery was in turn an important impetus for the Renaissance, by going way beyond the ancient Greeks, whose work had been the ultimate scientific authority; but I don't know how reliable *that* story is either.)

Comment: I've heard something similar about del Ferro: that he kept his solution of the cubic a secret so that he could use it to win mathematical contests. I don't have a reference for that though. Wikipedia seems to confirm it, but they don't make it sound like gambling, more like an academic duel - loser leaves town forever.

Comment: Yes, I mentioned this as an apropos to Cardano, not to gambling:
he published the solution, not the discoverer who kept it
to himself as a secret weapon, teaching it to Cardano but
on condition that it not be revealed.
The existence of such "academic duels" would be
(in the original question's words) a "cultural/social context"
for mathematical research quite different from what many (most?
all?) of us are used to.

Comment: From del Ferro's Wikipedia entry: "The loser in a challenge often lost funding or his university position." Makes the grant application process seem easy.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe an example can be the period of enlightenment. During the enlightenment period mathematics advanced a lot in part thanks to the new division of higher education in Paris. During this period many great minds like the three L`s (Lagrange, Laplace and Legendre) came up. As well as others such as Cauchy. This time period was also favored by the creation of the encyclopedia which contained many mathematical terms thanks to the work of d'Alembert.

Comment: I was at first temporarily confused what you mean by 'ilustration period'; enlightenment period or Age of Enlightenment are I think better in English, to express Ilustración (in the meaning of the epoque).

Answer (score 2):

I think there's two related issues here. I've heard some sociological theories suggest that the *answers* we get in math are socially influenced. This is clearly mistaken, because math is a purely logical discipline: once you pick axioms (and a system of logic, to be pedantic), your answers are fixed. Similarly in the physical sciences, once you pick your experiment, you have no control over the outcome.
The exception to this of course is when people disregard the strict rules of logic. Example: philosophers used to believe that Euclidean geometry was somehow 'automatic' (see e.g. Kant). There was a mathematician whose name escapes me who came extremely close to developing non-Euclidean geometry, but, after proving a number of theorems about it, concluded that there was a contradiction because the system was 'absurd' or something like that. But this is an example of somebody doing math 'wrongly.' Math done 'right' has consequences that are not socially influenced.

On the other hand, there's the question of *what we choose to study.* That is obviously going to be influenced by social and personal factors. For example I recall some stuff about how the ancient Greeks liked to think geometrically, whereas the ancient Chinese liked to think algebraically (and I think the ancient Arabic mathematicians as well). You can see this in the types of discoveries that they made. There are studies out there on what sorts of differences made this happen; I think there's even someone who conjectures that Westerners still tend to think more geometrically, and Easterners more algebraically, or something like that.

Comment: The conjectures in your last para have set off my Anachronism Klaxon...

Comment: Furthermore, I think your assessment in the first para is a bit too confident. It is true that mathematics can proceed logically from assumptions to conclusions, and that this process is not socially influenced in the sense claimed. On the other hand, social context (within the mathematical or professional community) can affect what goes into the assumptions and what significance is attached to the conclusions. See for instance the evolution of Elliott's classification program for (certain) $C^*$-algebras

Comment: You're probably right about the anachronisms. I read a description of some guy's research on this, not the research itself, so take it with a grain of salt. In my interactions I've known plenty of Asian geometers/topologists and plenty of Caucasian algebraists.
As to the other point, that's what I meant by my second paragraph. Once the assumptions are chosen, your answers are fixed, but culture can play a huge role in which axioms you choose to take (in other words, what math you choose to study). So I stand by my confident assessment:)

Comment: Dear Blake, The claims of the first para. don't seem to take into account that we are not automata generating lists of all possible sylogisms in proof space and attaching equal weight to each, but rather thinking beings who choose particular narrow paths to follow out of the enormous number of possible paths in proof space.  (Relatedly, in physics there can be substantial debate over the *interpretation* of an experiment --- see e.g. such debates in the development of quantum theory and in the possible interpretations of quantum mechanics --- and so the claim about physical sciences also ...

Comment: ... seems a bit overconfident to me.)  Regarding the final sentence concerning mathematicians from various countries/cultures and the directions of their mathematical strengths, since some of the strongest living geometers are Hironaka, Mori, Siu, and Yau, who were preceded by Chow, Chern, and Igusa, among others, it seems like complete nonsense (as most such generalizations tend to be).  Regards, Matthew

Comment: Interpretations of physical theories are really debates about which set of axioms to use. There are further problems with, e.g., forgetting to account for an experimental variable. As an undergraduate I spent a great deal of time studying the experimental mistakes people made trying to measure orthopositronium's halflife...  
Anyway sure, claiming there's a national/cultural difference in mathematical ability is nonsense, but I think there's probably something to the claim that historically the development of mathematics proceeded along those sorts of lines, until the 'merging' of the two.

Comment: But Blake, terms like "algebraic" and "geometric" run the risk of being anachronistic, or ahistorical. This is why historians of science are careful to try and avoid using terms with modern meanings to describe the thought processes of those in former eras. Incidentally, west and east of what? Rhode Island? The Urals? The Equator? (what, no Northener-Southener divides?)

Comment: Surely the ancient Greeks would find modern geometry terribly algebraic?  (And not only ‘algebraic geometry’.)

Comment: By the way, Saccheri is the name of the mathematician that escaped you: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giovanni_Girolamo_Saccheri 

Answer (score -7):

Pure mathematics has never been influenced by "social context" in any meaningful way. In particular, the claim that descriptive set theory was "deeply influenced by the religious movement of Name Worshiping in Russia" is absurd on its face and, as far as I can tell, supported by nothing more than speculation.

You all need to understand the context of this kind of claim: it comes from people who want to discredit science by showing that it arises from "social context" rather than rational thought. See [Sokal hoax](descriptive set theory (Egorov, Lusin, etc.) was deeply influenced by the religious movement of Name Worshiping in Russia), [science wars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Science_wars), [Social Text](http://socialtext.dukejournals.org/), etc.

Comment: Do you want us to take your word for it, or do you have *something* to back this up. This is not an answer, maybe a comment.

Comment: Nik, am I mistaken, or does that little photo of you seem to have a little bump in your cheek, right around where your tongue might be?

Comment: Lee, that is an amusing comment, because there isn't a bump in my photo. Did you really see one, or were you being tongue-in-cheek? (Now my head hurts.)

Comment: Serious, semi-serious, tongue-in-cheek, ironic, cynical, whatever. IMO this answer adds no relevant information, and as such should not be an *answer*. Please limit this type of contribution to **comments**. I consider such an answer essentially as spam. 

Comment: Dear quid, the answer seems to express a reasonable point of view. Certainly it is harder to give examples and even a detailed explanation to a phenomenon that Nik views as non-existing (in a meaningful way). 

Comment: Dear Gil Kalai, in various scientific disciplines the problem to establish the independence of some thing A of some other thing B arises. (In our case, A being 'pure mathematics' and B being 'social context'.) And, there are various ways to do this, leading perhaps not to a "proof" but at least to some significant evidence. (For instance one could evaluate how mathematics developped in different not to connected systems where a different social context was present.) Please note that I did not ask for examples or detailed explanation or even 'prove' I just asked for 'something'.  Furthermore   

Comment: it would also already help in assesing the plausibility of the point of view expressed to have some information what OP considers as 'in a meaningful way'. In some sense I agree with you that the POV is reasonable, yet mainly because all this is so vague that any 'naked' point of view is reasonable, after all we have Yemon Choi's oppossing point of view that this happens always. (Which in contrast to this one, while being only a *comment*, indeed was *accompanied by some explanation* how one should understand this claim.) So that it really comes down to what 'in a meaningful way' means. 

Comment: However, the developpment after my initial comment makes this answer even still worse. You say the answer seems to express a  reasonable point of view. *Yet, which one?!* It is (now) unclear, at least to me, whether this answer is actually to be taken at face value (my original assumption due to the qualification 'in a meaningful way' and since this would as you say at least give some content to the answer.)  Or, as ironic or a parody, then essentially expressing the opposite POV. Or something in between expressing still another POV. So, agreed, this question expresses some reasonable POV. 

Comment: Unfortunately it is (for me) impossible to know *which one*, making the answer one totally free of any actual information. As such I consider it as nothing but *noise*. Sorry, this got a bit long, I think I will stop here.  

Comment: Lee's right, there is a bump in the photo!

Comment: Quid, Nik expressed his opinion, which he regarded sufficiently important to make as a separate answer, that pure mathematics was not influenced by social contexts in a meaningful way. It is ok to disagree, and also to consider the answer more appropriate as a comment but I see no justification to the strong language against it.

Comment: Gil Kalai, first, a detail, strictly speacking OP did *not* express his opinion *but asserted a fact*. Second, as I said, yes OP expresses an opinion, but it is not even claear (to me) **which one**. Yet in any case, this willfully nonserious answer rather makes fun of the question. Maybe, we can discuss whether this is appropriate?  

Comment: Quid, maybe I am naive but I thought Nik just expressed his understanding regarding the question and did not try to make fun of the question or do anything like that. Maybe, Nik himself will open our eyes. (Certainly I did not want to annoy you.)

Comment: Gil Kalai, thank you for your concern, but I am always happy to discuss MO subjects with you. At first I also had this impression, and perhaps my initial comment was phrased a bit too sternly though I completely stand by its content; however, then Lee Mosher injected that this answer might be 'tongue in cheek' and Nik Weaver's response to this does not clarify this, making the answer *willfully* unclear.

Comment: I think "Sokal hoax" was meant to point to the corresponding Wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sokal_affair. (Perhaps there was an issue when copy-pasting the link when submitting the [last revision](https://mathoverflow.net/revisions/101068/3)…)